# Javascript Json Http Request

Tags: javascript, json, httprequest

When I enter the following link in my browser and then delete the first 39 characters and the last 2 then I have a valid JSON object.

```
http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=facebook&region=1&lang=en&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

My question is, what is the most concise way to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about titles. Titles should not just be a bunch of words.

Comment: This would actually be a good question if it had more details on the data and procedure

Answer (score 1):

You might notice the callback url parameter. This is meant to return a call to that callback function. This goes with some other APIs. Now, I can't say I've worked with this specific API before, but this should work:

Change your API call to this:

`http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=facebook&region=1&lang=en`

Answer (score 0):

You can take your URL to as string, as it probably already is. Then you can take the substring of this string including chars between the 40th and all the ones except the last 2:

```
 var myURL = 'blablabla';
 myURL = myURL.substring(40, myURL.length -3);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Done. I am sorry I thought it was obvious the explanation. Thanks